# WPF: How to center and animate an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, animation, itemscontrol, carousel

I'd like to use an ItemsControl which behaves somewhat carousel-like:

[image: ItemsControl]

I want the items which are all text to circle so that the selected item is always centered and the biggest. I should not be 3D since I like the fact that the unselected items don't overlap and are still readable. Most carousel implementations I saw made the impression to be too heavyweight for this scenario or to look good only with pictures.

I have the feeling this should be doable with some storyboards alone but it seems I'm not far enough into the WPF to get it done properly.

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adrianma/archive/2006/03/07/reusable-fisheye-grid-control-using-wpf-and-expression-interactive-designer.aspx) has a good description of how you can implement this

Comment: Well, thanks. It's not really what I want though since it doesn't really circles its content as I would like it to, it just changes heights depending on the mouse position. But maybe it's a start to mine it for parts of the implementation.